# What is the difference between "00-installer-config.yaml" and "50-cloud-init.yaml"

Tags: netplan

I have multiple Ubuntu 18.04 and Ubuntu 20.04 servers (some upgrades, some fresh installs) running on Hyper-V, Raspberry Pis, and the cloud. I have noticed that for configuring netplan, directory `/etc/netplan` sometimes contains `00-installer-config.yaml` file, and other times `50-cloud-init.yaml` file. The content and syntax on both is usually the same so why is the file name different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**00-installer-config.yaml** File is created by installer, subiquity.

**50-cloud-init.yaml** is the config that is created by cloud-init.

They are the same but they were created by different means.

Answer (score 1):

I am in an Advanced Linux class, and found myself asking the same thing.
The **00-installer-config.yaml** file is supposed to be for **v20**, the **50-cloud-init.yaml** for **v18**, however my VM must think otherwise. I myself found the 00-installer-config.yaml file in my /etc/netplan folder instead. I then rebuilt the 50-cloud-ini.yaml file and removed the 00-installer-config.yaml file. After that, I went to /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d and looked through these few file and noticed a "subiquity....." file. This file had one line in it that appeared to act as the "network: {config: disabled}" from 99-disable-network-config.cfg file that disables netplan....so I hashed this out.
I then issued **netplan generate** then **netplan apply** and rebooted. All is well here now. However, I too need to know for my own development why this may happen.

I hope there is enough information I have provided to further your solution.

Comment: v20 vs. v18 of what?  You mean for 18.04 vs. 20.04?

Comment: My appologies, Ubuntu

Comment: I just went through a similar issue, and I don't think that removing the `network: {config:disabled}` is necessary, or even correct. I read a blog post saying to keep it, and it worked for me: https://www.linuxtechi.com/assign-static-ip-address-ubuntu-20-04-lts/

Comment: What you experienced may be different. But deeming something "incorrect" while your situation is subjective, helps nobody. I fixed the situation I went through the way I described. Find me a blogger who knows why I had the v20 file on fresh installed v18, that would have been more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I want to share this with you and i don't know this will help or not, i was working on a scenario and i have created several machines on vmware i noticed those with dhcp have 50-cloud-init.yaml in the netplan and those with static address have 00-installer-config.yaml in the netplan, when i was installing them i set static address for some of em and some other dynamically it was due to implementing some tests.